# document not saved docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi

i am sending a document in my application to another user who can sign that document online using docusign. I am doing this using the send on behalf option.

Following is the header that i am using:

```
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>" . $behalf_email ."</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";
```

The problem is that even though i am able to send the document successfully and other users can sign it online , the sent document is not visible when i go to my docusign profile. If i dont use the send on behalf functionality the document along with the status, i.e out for signature  or signed will be shown in my profile. Whats going on here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by saying "DocuSign profile", you mean what you see when you log into the DocuSign web console (after sending an Envelope via the API):

- A sent Envelope will only be visible in the Sender's **Sent Items** folder.
- If you **DO** use "Send On Behalf Of" to send the Envelope via API, then DocuSign considers the Sender of the Envelope to be the user account that corresponds to the "Send On Behalf Of" value.  If that person logs into the DocuSign web console using their credentials, they should see the sent envelope in their **Sent Items** folder.  The Envelope will only reside in that user's **Sent Items** folder, because they are considered the Sender of the Envelope.
- If you **DO NOT** use "Send On Behalf Of" to send the Envelope via API, then the user account that corresponds to the credentials you specify in the header is considered the Sender of the Envelope. If you log into the DocuSign web console using those credentials, you should see the sent Envelope in the **Sent Items** folder. Once again, the Envelope will only reside in that user's **Sent Items** folder, because they are considered the Sender of the Envelope.